# How to display hyperlink on Angular Formly form

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I would like to include a simple link on my Formly form such as

```
<a href="https://google.com">Search</a>
```

However I can not find how to extend the `a` html element

My custom Formly component is

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'formly-link-component',
 template: `
 <a [href]="to.url">{{ to.title }}</a>
 `,
})
export class FormlyLinkComponent extends FieldType {

}
```

I have added the custom component as a type in app.module.ts

```
 { name: "link", component: FormlyLinkComponent },
```

And the form configuration JSON is

```
{
  "schema": {
    "title": "A registration form",
    "description": "A simple form example.",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "firstName",
      "lastName"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "webLink": {
        "type": "link",
        "url": "https:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/Chuck_Norris",
        "title": "Click Me"
      },
      "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "First name",
        "default": "Chuck"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Last name"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Age"
      },
      "bio": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Bio"
      },
      "password": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Password",
        "minLength": 3
      },
      "telephone": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Telephone",
        "minLength": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "model": {
    "lastName": "Norris",
    "age": 75,
    "bio": "Roundhouse kicking asses since 1940",
    "password": "noneed"
  }
}
```

Stackblitz is here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-material-fv4a2x?file=src/assets/simple.json

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code in the alink.type.ts file to this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "formly-link-component",
  template: `
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Something</a>
  `
})
```

This did show up on the UI. So you might be missing some input params to the component? You can try this out. I hope it helps. Thank you.

P.S. "Something" and google.com are placeholders for testing.

Comment: I don't see in the documentation how to configure the parameters when loading the fields from JSON